# How to substring column in R using different character locations for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, substring

I want to create an additional column in a dataframe, which is a substring from an existing column in the dataframe, but using different start and end points for each row.

Specifically, the column "codes" in the example below contains a single colon character ":" somewhere in the string. This location varies in each string. I want to take the two characters before and two characters after the colon, as well as the colon.

An example of what I currently have:

```
letters <- c("A", "B", "C")

codes <- c("lksjdfi99:99lksjdf", "nsj78:12osjsm", "a12:67opaidsf")

df <- data.frame(letters, codes)

print(df)

  letters              codes
1       A lksjdfi99:99lksjdf
2       B      nsj78:12osjsm
3       C      a12:67opaidsf
```

This is an example of what I would like to have:

```
  letters              codes new_col
1       A lksjdfi99:99lksjdf   99:99
2       B      nsj78:12osjsm   78:12
3       C      a12:67opaidsf   12:67
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` in `base R`

```
df$new_col <- sub("\\D+(\\d+:\\d+)\\D+", "\\1", df$codes)
```

-output

```
> df
  letters              codes new_col
1       A lksjdfi99:99lksjdf   99:99
2       B      nsj78:12osjsm   78:12
3       C      a12:67opaidsf   12:67
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
df$new_col <- str_extract(df$codes, "\\d+:\\d+")
df
  letters              codes new_col
1       A lksjdfi99:99lksjdf   99:99
2       B      nsj78:12osjsm   78:12
3       C      a12:67opaidsf   12:67
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
str_replace(df$codes,".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*", "\\1")
```

or, in `base R`:

```
gsub(".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*", "\\1", df$codes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
   extract(codes, 'new_col', '(\\d+:\\d+)', remove = FALSE)
  letters              codes new_col
1       A lksjdfi99:99lksjdf   99:99
2       B      nsj78:12osjsm   78:12
3       C      a12:67opaidsf   12:67
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  separate(codes, c("split1", "split2"), remove=FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("split"), parse_number)) %>% 
  mutate(new_col= paste(split1, split2, sep=":"), .keep="unused")
```

output:

```
  letters              codes new_col
1       A lksjdfi99:99lksjdf   99:99
2       B      nsj78:12osjsm   78:12
3       C      a12:67opaidsf   12:67
```